# create a dataframe mask and sum columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
# dictionary with list object in values
details = {
    'A1' : [1,3,4,5],
    'A2' : [2,3,5,6],
    'A3' : [4,3,2,6],
}
  
# creating a Dataframe object 
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
```

I want to query on each columns with the follow conditions to obtain a boolean mask and then perform the sum on axis=1

- A1 >= 3
- A2 >=3
- A3 >=4

I would like to end-up with the following dataframe

```
details = {
    'A1' : [1,3,4,5],
    'A2' : [2,3,5,6],
    'A3' : [4,3,2,6],
    'score' : [1,2,2,3]
}
  
# creating a Dataframe object 
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
```

How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since your operators are the same, you can try numpy broadcasting

```py
import numpy as np

df['score'] = (df.T >= np.array([3,3,4])[:, None]).sum()
```

```
print(df)

   A1  A2  A3  score
0   1   2   4      1
1   3   3   3      2
2   4   5   2      2
3   5   6   6      3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
df.assign(score = (df >=[3,3,4]).sum(1))
 
   A1  A2  A3  score
0   1   2   4      1
1   3   3   3      2
2   4   5   2      2
3   5   6   6      3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specifically align your comparators to each column, you can pass them as a dictionary that is alignable against the `DataFrames` columns.

```py
>>> comparisons = pd.Series({'A1': 3, 'A2': 3, 'A3': 4})
>>> df['score'] = df.ge(comparisons).sum(axis=1)
>>> df
   A1  A2  A3  score
0   1   2   4      1
1   3   3   3      2
2   4   5   2      2
3   5   6   6      3
```

---

For a little more manual control, you can always subset your `df` according to your comparators before performing the comparisons.

```py
comparisons = pd.Series({'A1': 3, 'A2': 3, 'A3': 4})
df['score'] = df[comparisons.index].ge(comparisons).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: When I try the 2 solutions above, I have the following error message: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 4: given 3

Comment: You can wrap your compator in a `pd.Series` I've updated my answer as such.